# sed + remove word from text without additional spaces

Tags: regex, sed

we want to remove the word - `-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly` from the following file

```
more hdfs.conf

SHARED_HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Xms{{namenode_heapsize}}"
```

so we did the following:

```
sed -i -E  's/\-XX:\+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly//g' hdfs.conf
```

**-E enables extended regular expressions (needed for + and grouping). , and I using the "" before the "-" and "+"**

Note - appreciate comments comments about my sed syntax and if I missing something

the problem with my sed is that we have one additional space when we delete the word ( according to my sed suggestion )

example of what we get

```
more hdfs.conf

SHARED_HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8  -Xms{{namenode_heapsize}}"
```

instead to get the line without additional spaces as

```
more hdfs.conf

SHARED_HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-server -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -Xms{{namenode_heapsize}}"
```

so how to improve my sed syntax in order to delete also the additional space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra spaces *shouldn't* matter to whatever parses those options later unless it's really badly written code. Assuming that's the case and an extra space causes an error...

As always, if you want to **ed**it a file in a script and your first inclination is to turn to `sed -i`, I suggest using `ed` instead. Unlike `sed`'s `-i` option, it's standardized and behaves the same everywhere, meaning you're less likely to run into unwelcome surprises when running in different environments. You can adjust the following regular expression to work with `sed` if really desired, though:

```bash
ed -s hdfs.conf <<'EOF'
/^SHARED_HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS=/ s/\( *\)-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly */\1/
w
EOF
```

The trick here is to also match 0 or more preceding and following spaces, but only leave one of the two (The first in this case) present in the output.

This also only tries to substitute on the line setting the particular variable whose contents you're interested in, in case the option you're removing appears elsewhere (In a comment, say) and you want to keep that occurrence.

---

And since this is tagged perl, a `perl` version:

```bash
perl -pi -e 's/\s*\K\Q-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly\E\s*// if /^SHARED_HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS/' hdfs.conf
```

(Stuff inside `\Q` ... `\E` is treated literally so the `+` doesn't need to be escaped, and `\K` basically discards what matches before it from the final matched text, meaning you don't need the explicit capture group of the leading whitespace characters (Which `\s` matches instead of a literal space))

Comment: The classic example of where `sed -i` causes problems is in how the Mac and FreeBSD implementations have a mandatory argument to the option, but GNU/NetBSD/OpenBSD ones have an optional one. And I wouldn't be surprised if it's not supported at all on remaining commercial Unixes like AIX that sometimes still pop up. But `ed`, man! It's the standard!

Comment: about yours Perl , I think is the best solution and I also test it ,

Comment: The leading `\s*\K` is useless. It should be removed. /// `\Q..\E` to avoid escaping a `+` is weird to me.

Comment: @ikegami  , if you have other solution for deletion -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly , then you can post it , about the current solution on this original post its works fine

Comment: I didn't say otherwise? And seeing as the oddity I mentioned directly lead to your new Question, and seeing as you repeated the mistake in the code in that Question as well, you're in no position to make that argument!